# Cakephp 3 count how much users in group

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Guys am trying to show number of users in specific groups. I try with associations but not working. In list where am listing `user groups` i want show `number_users_in_group`

I have two tables:

1st `Users` and second `User groups`

**Users table:**

```
  id  group_id  status  username       password
```

**User groups table:**

```
group_id  name   permission
```

To show all groups i use this method:

```
/**
 * Index method
 *
 * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
 */
public function index()
{
    $usersGroup = $this->paginate($this->UsersGroup);

    $this->set(compact('usersGroup'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['usersGroup']);
}
```

And in `index.cp` i foreach this results. So in this result i want to add number for each of group how much users is in group..

**Example:**

1. Administrator (5) <--- 5 users in administarator group
2. Moderator (3)

How to do this?

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description! Please always show what you've done, and be more specific as to what _exactly_ happens, and what you'd expect to happen instead. Also show your debugging attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#retrieving-associated-data)

```
 public function index()
    {
        $usersGroups = $this->UsersGroup->find('all',['contain'=>['Users']]);

        $this->set('userGroups',$this->paginate($usersGroups));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['usersGroups']);
    };
```

for this you must declare the association in user group model

```
$this->hasMany('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id'
        ]);
```

and now you can `count` in view loop

```
foreach ($userGroups as $group)
echo count($group->users);
```

Comment: A **[counter cache](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html)** will probably be more efficient.

Comment: @Mazba its work thanks. @ndm also ty i will try `counter cache` sounds good`